# Is there a way to make the "envit Event" element from WP Page Builder show upcoming events?

Tags: wordpress, events

I have to manage a website for work that was built by somebody not employed any more and I'm having a hard time with this one element. The page was built using the WP Page Builder plugin and one of the features on the front page is supposed to show upcoming events. The element that was added to do this is called "envit Event", I don't know if that is part of the WP Page Builder or another plugin as I can't find anything for that.

The problem is that it can only show events either in ascending or descending order, but does not regard whether or not the date has already passed. So it shows only the first or last events of all uploaded events, not the upcoming ones. In its menu there are few options, one of them being "Extra class name" which I suspect to be of help here, but I have no idea what to put into this field.

Can anybody help me have the website show upcoming events with what I have here?

Thanks,
Alex